# ArrayFormula with SUMIFS not Working in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs, named-ranges

I'm encountering a challenge with an ArrayFormula in Google Sheets that utilizes the SUMIFS function. Here's the scenario:
I have a report with data in columns SpoPartnerShare, SpoMonth, and SpoPartnerId in the sheet (Spo), along with another sheet (Sum) containing a dropdown menu in cell C1 for selecting the "Reporting Month." Additionally, in sheet Sum, I have the SumPartnerId.
The following single-cell formula works flawlessly when copied down a column:

```
=SUMIFS(SpoPartnerShare, SpoMonth, $C$1, SpoPartnerId, A2)
```

This formula leverages the value in C1 (Reporting Month) to filter SpoMonth and then sums SpoPartnerShare based on matching SumPartnerId in column A (A2 or A50 depending on the formula's placement).
The Problem:
When attempting to convert this to an ArrayFormula as shown below:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIFS(SpoPartnerShare, SpoMonth, SumRepMonth, SpoPartnerId, SumPartnerId))
```

I only see zeros. Despite the logic appearing consistent, the ArrayFormula isn't producing the expected results.
Request for Assistance:
I am seeking guidance on fixing the ArrayFormula or exploring alternative approaches to achieve the desired outcome. I have tried various AI chats, forums, and solutions without success, investing significant time into troubleshooting this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUMIFS` does not work nicely with `ARRAYFORMULA`, you can concatenate the conditions and use [`SUMIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en):

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(SumRepMonth&SumPartnerId,C1&SpoPartnerId,SpoPartnerShare))
```

Or use the [`MAP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en) function:

```cpp
=MAP(SumPartnerId,
   LAMBDA(SumPartnerId_,
     SUMIFS(SpoPartnerShare,SpoMonth,C1,SpoPartnerId,SumPartnerId_)))
```

Comment: With MAP, it works.

Thank you so much for helping me with this